# executable made with py2exe doesn't run on windows xp 32bit

Tags: python, windows, architecture, py2exe

I created an executable with py2exe on a 64bit windows 7 machine, and distributed the program.

On a windows xp 32bit machine the program refuses to run exhibiting the following behavior:

> a popup window says: program.exe is
>   not a valid win32 application.
>
> The command prompt window says "access
>   denied"

I checked for permissions and the user has full control and complete ownership of the file and its parent directories. So that can't be the issue.

The only feasible possibility I can image is an OS/architectural incompatibility. How should I fix this?

My setup.py file used to generate the executable:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['xerxes2excel.py'])
```

I ran the following to generate the exe:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Comment: Try creating the executable using a 32bit machine

Comment: wouldn't it be safe to say you probably created a 64-bit executable, which won't run on a 32-bit processor?

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, that's my assumption. Is there a way to create a 32bit executable on a 64bit machine? Through some sort of emulation magicks?

Comment: there might be, but you'll be more likely to get an answer if you change your question to what you just asked me. I personally haven't used py2exe

Comment: Windows 7 - run `py2exe` and the `cmd` session in compatibility. Perhaps that will helps

Comment: try to produce the executable on a virtual machine with windowsXP and python 32 bit running on it

Comment: Turns out the only incompatibility was the python interpreter. I installed a 32bit python and 32 bit versions of all the modules I used and it works now. There's still problems, but that's a different issue. Thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need to install 32-bit python and 32-bit py2exe on your machine....  see [Can 64-bit python create 32-bit Windows executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935502/can-64-bit-python-create-32-bit-windows-executables)

Comment: Did this and it worked, turns out the python interpreter was the only thing having compatibility issues.

Answer (score 4):

A common problem when you generate executable on Windows 7 and deploy on Windows XP.

According with the py2exe tutorial, you need include the MVC DLL. But the tutorial is old and the script given search only in one directory. Before, the directory contained all DLL and the manifest, but nowadays it contains only the DLL. You need to specify another directory for the manifest file. If you don't do that, you will have this kind of error:

```
this application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect
```

If you are on Windows 7 64 bits, you need the Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL. Don't forget the manifest that isn't in the same directory in Windows 7. You need to adapt the script like this:

```
data_files = [("VC90", glob(r'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\*.*')),
            ("VC90", glob(r'C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91.manifest'))
]
setup(
    data_files=data_files,
    console = [{'script': "C:\test\my_program.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Now you can deploy the "dist" directory that contains all files and dependencies.

Comment: you should include from glob import glob