# Packaging python for 32 bit WIndows XP from a 64 bit windows 7 machine using py2exe

Tags: python, dll, windows-xp, py2exe, windows-7-x64

I am trying to package a python application on my 64 bit windows 7 machine using py2exe.
The final target of this application are 32 bit windows machines.

I am using 32 bit python 2.7 on the 64 bit windows 7 machine. When I package the application , py2exe warns me of several DLLs from the system32 directory that need to be packaged .

The built exe now fails to run on the destination machines : windows XP (32 bit) and windows Vista (32 bit) with the message saying C:\myapp\bin\WS2_32.dll is corrupted and I need to check it against the Windows installation.

Checking :
WIndows 7 64 bit : system32 directory WS2_32.dll has size 290kb
Windows XP 32 bit : system directory has size 80 kb

My question is , can I build a XP/Vista 32 bit application using py2exe from Windows 7 given these differences in DLL size.

I also tried replacing the C:\myapp\bin\WS2_32.dll with the XP DLL..but this time the application didnt launch.

Comment: see some other answers on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378673/executable-made-with-py2exe-doesnt-run-on-windows-xp-32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

py2exe tells you:

> Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
>   you may or may not need to distribute them.
>
> Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
>   *make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system*.

WS2_32.dll is part of the operating system.

Comment: Once I packaged without the dlls that py2exe warned in the end of its build output (the ones from the system32 folder). The application worked just great on Windows XP 32 bit. I am sure it will also work on Vista 32 bit. ..Thanks