# Making a x86 .exe on a x64 machine

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cx-freeze

and thank you for your answer in advance. I am making a python program to automate something for my friend, and converted it into a .exe file with cx_Freeze so I could give it to him. But I have a x64 machine and he has a x86 machine. Can anyone please tell me how to make a x86 .exe file on my PC. I'm using Win 10 x64 and Python 3.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can 64-bit python create 32-bit Windows executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935502/can-64-bit-python-create-32-bit-windows-executables)

Answer (score 0):

The .exe output actually depends on the installation you are using (I'm assuming x64) so if you used an x86bit or x32bit Python installation it will output the bit version your installation is (I know both will run on x64 computers) and just freeze in the normal way.

Bear in mind that x32 works on x86, x64 as well so you might do best with that bit version.